# Concatenate 2 dataframes having different values

Tags: python, pandas

we have the following two dataframes respectively.

```
Dataframe 1:
id =[30,30]
month =[1,3]
less_data =['pravin','shashi']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(id,month,less_data)),columns =['id','month','less_data'])

Dataframe 2:
id =[30,30]
month =[1,2]
less_data =['amol','pinak']


df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(id,month,less_data)),columns =['id','month','zero_data'])
```

and expected output:

```
id  month   less_data   zero_data
30  1       pravin      amol
30  2                   pinak
30  3       shashi
```

How can I use pd.concat to achieve this or suggest better solution for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `pd.concat`:

```py
dfn = pd.concat([
           df.set_index(['id','month']),
          df2.set_index(['id','month'])
        ], axis = 1).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do an outer join:

```py
df.join(df2.set_index(['id', 'month']), how='outer', on=['id', 'month'])
```

Comment: Your quotes were not valid python quotes and please use code formatting for your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.merge` on `month` and `id`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

id =[30,30]
month =[1,3]
less_data =['pravin','shashi']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(id,month,less_data)),columns =['id','month','less_data'])

id =[30,30]
month =[1,2]
less_data =['amol','pinak']


df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(id,month,less_data)),columns =['id','month','zero_data'])

##### Merge can be thought of joins in SQL
>>> df_merge = pd.merge(df,df2,on=['id','month'],how='outer')
>>> df_merge
   id  month less_data zero_data
0  30      1    pravin      amol
1  30      3    shashi       NaN
2  30      2       NaN     pinak
```

Comment: If You can see, my expected output is not like that, id row value :: 30 is missing

Comment: Updated the answer to accommodate the `id` , do accept the answer if it solves your question :)

Comment: Yep totally agree with that , I have removed it from the answer